# UWP/C# Applying selected Colour to NavigationView

Tags: c#, uwp

Finally managed to get the Colorpickers down and sorted and they currently work on a OnNavigateTo basis.

When I pick a color from color picker I would like to to be applied eith instantly to the Foreground of my NavigationViewItems OR apply once i click the button within the settings page called TextColourApply_Click.

The mentioned color picker is on the **settingspage** currently and the NavigationViewItems are on the **MainPage**.

I was looking at doing a UI refresh but this doesnt work with UWP as far as i can tell. As a work around, i was looking at doing a current Frame navigate but this doesnt work

I have the following that allows the selected colour to apply when navigating back to the "MainPage":

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    SolidColorBrush DefaultTextColour = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultTextColour"] as SolidColorBrush;

    if (ColourSelections.TextColour != null)
    {
        DefaultTextColour = ColourSelections.TextColour;
    }

    foreach (var item in NavView.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>())
    {
        item.Foreground = DefaultTextColour;
    }       
}
```

Any ideas on how to impliment this would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: basically to summarize : you want the updated color whenever you press the apply button instead of whenever you navigate to the page?

Comment: and this apply buttons is present on settings page right? I think your ideal solution is that whenever you select a color from colorpicker it should change the foreground of navigationviewitems right?

Comment: Please make sure to update your question and put the complete context of your use case, you need to mention about colorpicker event, and the static class you were using. So that others can understand the complete context of your question, hve a look at the answer so you can better understand what to provide in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your desired behaviour is following :

> When I pick a color from **color picker** it should be applied instantly to the Foreground of my **NavigationViewItems** and color picker is on settings page.

In that case you do not need **OnNavigatedTo** on your **MainPage** and you do not need the **Apply** as well, So remove your OnNavigatedTo method also remove the Apply button from your settings page and then Just do the following:

Create a public static property within your ShellPage (the page where your NavigationView exists) that will expose your NavigationView, and make sure to initialize it within the constructor of your ShellPage.

```
public static NavigationView MyNavView;
public ShellPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MyNavView = NavView; //here you assign your navigation view to the public static property so you can access it outside this shell page as well.
}
```

Now within the **colorChanged** event (in your settings page) of your color picker assign the color to the foreground of your navigationmenuItems.

```
private void TextColourPicker_ColorChanged(ColorPicker sender, ColorChangedEventArgs args)
{
    SolidColorBrush DefaultTextColour = new SolidColorBrush(TextColourPicker.Color);

    foreach (var item in ShellPage.MyNavView.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>())
    {
        item.Foreground = DefaultTextColour;
    } 
}
```

and just to make sure that whenever your app is loaded for the first time you get the default color set in your resources, assign a Loaded event to your NavigationView and set the default color in there.

add the loaded event in xaml like this :

```
<NavigationView x:Name="NavView" Loaded="NavView_Loaded">
```

and the event in your backend will be :

```
private void NavView_Loaded(object sender, object args)
{
    SolidColorBrush DefaultTextColour = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultTextColour"] as SolidColorBrush;    

    foreach (var item in NavView.MenuItems.OfType<NavigationViewItem>())
    {
        item.Foreground = DefaultTextColour;
    } 
}
```

Please note that now you do not even need the public static class you were using before for saving the colors, so you can remove that class as well.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the poor question. I struggle with wording them. I know what i want to achieve in my head but its hard to explain sometimes. I will be sure to update the question with the right information shortly

Comment: its ok you will learn the more you practice, may I suggest some c# beginner and intermediate courses? and there is also a uwp beginner course I can recommend, these courses will solidify your basics and will make your life easier in the long run.